# How to make process "terminable" only by SIGHUP or SIGKILL?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, process, kill

I wrote a script that should kill stuck processes. At first, it tries the weakest  SIGTERM, if it doesn't work, it tries SIGHUP, and if even that doesn't help, it'll do a SIGKILL. Now I want to try if this script work practically.

How can I make process stuck or jammed, so it can be stoppable only by HUP or KILL signal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the simplest way would be to write a minimal bash script, using the builtin `trap` to specify a custom signal handler:

```
#!/bin/bash

function mysighandler {
  printf 'ignoring TERM signal\n'
}

trap mysighandler SIGTERM

while :
do
  printf 'Running. . .\n'
  sleep 2
done
```

You could set the handler to the null string, which would cause the signal to be ignored silently - but creating a minimal handler allows you to confirm that it's been intercepted.

Alternatively, write a small C program that uses the `signal` API - see `man 2 signal`.